# Print double quotes in Forth

Tags: forth

The word `."` prints a string. More precisely it compiles the `(.")` and the string up to the next `"` in the currently compiled word.

But how can I print

> That's the "question".

with Forth?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a Forth-2012 System (e.g. Gforth) you can use string literals with escaping via the word [`s\"`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/file/Seq) as:

```
: foo ( -- ) s\" That's the \"question\"." type ;
```

In a Forth-94 system (majority of standard systems) you can use arbitrary parsing and the word [`sliteral`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/string/SLITERAL) as:

```
: foo ( -- ) [ char | parse That's the "question".| ] sliteral type ;
```

A string can be also extracted up to the end of the line (without printable delimiter); a multi-line string can be extracted too.

Specific helpers for particular cases can be easily defined.
For example, see the word [`s$`](http://forth.sourceforge.net/word/s-dollar/index.html) for string literals that are delimited by any arbitrary printable character, e.g.:

```
  s$ `"test" 'passed'` type
```

Answer (score 7):

Old school:

```
34 emit
```

Output:

```
"
```

Using `gforth`:

```
: d 34 emit ;
cr ." That's the " d ." question" d ." ." cr
```

Output:

```
That's the "question".
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard. In ciforth compatible systems you can use double quotes by doubling them (feature present since 2001). Also you use permanent strings initiated by " (a 2012 standard feature) ad it becomes:

```
"That's the ""question""." TYPE
```